# Animating a horizontal translation of Fragments with objectAnimator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, objectanimator

I want to animate the transition between fragments as sliding in and out horizontally.

The problem is, right now in my `objectAnimator`, I hardcoded the `valueTo` and `valueFrom` fields as below:

---

slide_in_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
android:propertyName="x"
android:valueFrom="1280"
android:valueTo="0"
android:valueType="floatType" />
```

slide_out_to_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" 
android:propertyName="x"
android:valueFrom="0"
android:valueTo="-1280"
android:valueType="floatType" />
```

---

But this doesn't look good on all devices. How could I use values like `100%` and `0%` like you can with Activities. I saw somewhere that I'd have to create `getX()` and `setX()` methods in my fragments but I'm not sure about how to go about implementing them. Also, if so, would I have to implement the methods for ALL of my fragments, or just for the `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAnimator works on absolute values. Alternate solution is to use view animations as you can specify fractions

slide_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
             android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
             android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

Load Animation

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: How would I set the animation to the fragment during the fragment transaction? (rather than to a view as you suggested)